# Get the monthly observation data from daily dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get a monthly observation data from the daily data in pandas. That means, I want to get the data at every 5th day of the month (2011-01-05; 2011-02-05; 2011-03-05...2011-12-05) or the closest trading day to that date (e.g if 03-05 is not existed, it will search 2011-03-06). How can i do that?

The dataframe looks something like:

```
Date           Close
2011-01-01     100.99
2011-01-02     100.65
......
2011-12-31     76.08
```

Answer (score 1):

Below answer will solve your problem but there is a caveat that there should be atleast a single day data for each month!

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['day'] = df.Date.dt.day
df['month'] = df.Date.dt.month
df['year'] = df.Date.dt.year

def get_nearest_time_data(df, day):
    newdf = pd.DataFrame()
    for month in range(1,13):
        daydf = df[(df.day==day) & (df.month==month)]
        while (daydf.shape[0]==0):
            day+=1
            daydf = df[(df.day==day) & (df.month==month)]  
        newdf = pd.concat([newdf,daydf], ignore_index=True)
    return newdf

get_nearest_time_data(df, 5)
```